# Discord bot 3rd party API OAuth2 integration

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I'm working on a Discord bot that is supposed to return, via the [Canvas LMS API](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/), lists of user courses, assignment notifications, etc.

The easiest way to do this is probably asking the user to provide their canvas authentication token through the bot, but that's obviously against who knows how many terms of services.

I'm somewhat familiar with OAuth2 workflow but am very confused about how to implement one with the discord bot as my app and the canvas class details as my protected resource.

I'm also confused on how to implement an OAuth2 workflow without a user or web interface, as a discord bot is more of a CLI-type thing. Also very confused regarding the `redirect_uri` for canvas when there is no web interface or website for the authentication process.

Tried the OAuth2 workflow by attempting a Canvas GET request, using this endpoint:

```
https://<canvas-install-url>/login/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXX&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://example.com/oauth_complete&state=YYY&scope=<value_1>%20<value_2>%20<value_n>
```

via Postman. Endpoint info can be found [here](https://canvas.instructure.com/doc/api/file.oauth_endpoints.html#get-login-oauth2-auth).

Not sure what to put for `client_id` as canvas only lets me create an access token. Also confused on what to put for `redirect_uri` because my app isn't web based.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the first thing you'll need to do is generate both `client_id` and `secret` values. From Canvas LMS' documentation it reads that:

> To obtain these application credentials, you will need to register your application. (...) For Canvas Cloud (hosted by Instructure), developer keys are issued by the admin of the institution. (...) For open source Canvas users, you can generate a client ID and secret in the Site Admin account of your Canvas install.

If your scenario fits the latter description (of the open-source usage), there's a simple guide on how to generate them [here](https://community.canvaslms.com/t5/Admin-Guide/How-do-I-manage-developer-keys-for-an-account/ta-p/249). This is also where you set the valid redirect URI(s) you'll be using.

Once this is done, your Discord bot would make a `GET HTTPS` request to

```
https://<canvas-install-url>/login/oauth2/auth?client_id={client_id}&response_type=code&state={state}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}
```

Where:

- `{client_id}` is the value you've just generated.
- `{state}` is a value that should serve as a unique identifier of the authenticating user, as it will be sent back to you as a query parameter of the `redirect_uri`, so you can link the request you will receive on your application with the user that is being authenticated. You can use, for example, a generated UUID here.

Once the user succesfully authenticates, a request will be sent to the supplied `redirect_uri` value with a `code` and `state` query parameters.

Your application does not *need* a web interface to handle this request, but it must at least serve a web server to where it can be sent to.

You can serve a web server directly within your Discord bot's application using `express` or any other web server frameworks such as `koa`, `fastify` or even node's `http` library.

Once the request is received, your application should exchange the `code` value with an actual `access_token`.

This can be accomplished by issuing a `POST HTTPS` request to

```
https://<canvas-install-url>/login/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={client_id}&client_secret={client_secret}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&code={code}
```

Note that the same `redirect_uri` value used in the previous request must be supplied.

Canvas' server would respond with (an example):

```json
{
  "access_token": "1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "user": {"id":42, "name": "Jimi Hendrix"},
  "refresh_token": "tIh2YBWGiC0GgGRglT9Ylwv2MnTvy8csfGyfK2PqZmkFYYqYZ0wui4tzI7uBwnN2",
  "expires_in": 3600,
  "canvas_region": "us-east-1"
}
```

And from here you can save the tokens linked to the user's Discord account and make requests to the API as needed.

Comment: My canvas instance is run by my university, and I have not been issued a developer key. Regarding open-source canvas, I do not have the admin section on my account. Thank you for the help.